# Push to bpf map stack type

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I'm looking for a method to send data from userspace to bpf program in Linux.
I use libbpf in userspace and bpf_helpers in bpf program in kernel.
I now can send data from kernel to user by ringbuf and other.
but I want to use stack and queue for this. I can't find function that handles queue or stack in userspace and I still confused.
My question is: how can I send data from userspace to bpf program using stack or queue and get it in my bpf program, as what we do in bcc with `bpf['queue'].push` in userspace for example and `queue.peek(&val);` in bpf program.

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **use the usual `bpf_map_update_elem` and `bpf_map_lookup_elem` functions** for `BPF_MAP_TYPE_QUEUE` and `BPF_MAP_TYPE_STACK` maps.

You can find several examples in the kernel source code:

- [Stack example with push and peek](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/test_maps.c#L611-L620)
- [Queue example with push and peek](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/test_maps.c#L553-L562)
- [Example handling both stack and queue maps](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/prog_tests/queue_stack_map.c#L42)

Comment: Thank you! can you please answer my this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653926/474031) too?